# How to adjust line numbers of algorithm2e package?

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

When using line numbers in the algorithm2e package, the line numbers are placed left of the text block, not directly below the text.
See page 5 of the [algorithm2e manual](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf).

Is it possible to place them below the text ?

Update: Line numbering now:

```
   Input ...
   Output ...
1: Code ...
```

Line numbering I want:

```
Input ...
Output ...
1: Code ...
```

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to do this is to use the formatting commands `\Indm` and `\Indp` to decrease and increase the indentation.  Used around the input/output commands makes these lines flushleft, just like the subsequent line numbers.  The example below shows this in action in a cut-down version of the second example from the manual.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
  \SetKwData{Left}{left}
  \SetKwData{Up}{up}
  \SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\Indm  
  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\Indp
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{ 
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```

For more general indentation changes there is `\Indentp`, which is defined in the style class, but not mentioned in the manual.  `\Indm` is equivalent to `\Indentp{-1em}`, `\Indp` is `\Indentp{1em}`.  There is also `\Indmm` and `\Indpp` which adjust the indentation by `0.5em`.  You need an extra `0.5em` for each extra digit of line number.
In particular, if you have two digit line numbers you can use `\Indm\Indmm` as follows:

[image: Sample two digit output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\IncMargin{1.5em}
\begin{algorithm}
  \SetKwData{Left}{left}
  \SetKwData{Up}{up}
  \SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
  \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}
  \SetKwInOut{Output}{output}

\Indm\Indmm
  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\Indp\Indpp
  \BlankLine
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{ 
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{ 
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{ 
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
  \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{ 
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\; }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
    \BlankLine
    \Indm\Indmm
  \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
  \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
\Indp\Indpp
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1.5em}

\end{document}
```

There is no internal variable storing the width of the line numbers.  The package uses `\llap` to them in a box of width zero, with the numbers plus their space from the algorithm sticking out to the right of this box.  As the examples in the documentation indicate, it is up to the user to adjust the margins to suit the given algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Put `\IncMargin{1em} \DecMargin{1em}` around your algorithm.

```
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}
```

Comment: This might be an answer to the question, but a full example is preferred