# How to align algorithm with text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e, line-numbering

I am using the `algorithm2e` package for a paper, and I am using it as follows:

```
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

Everything works OK, however, when I added the `linesnumbered` directive (not sure how is that called in latex) to the package declaration, I noticed that the algorithm gets out of the margin of the rest of text.

The following image shows the issue, you can see that after line #9, it should be #10, however, you can only see #0, because the 1 got covered by the green line.

[image]

Is there a way to force the algorithm to move a bit to the right?

I am using: Texstudio under linux

**Update:** Marked as duplicated with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86580/how-to-adjust-line-numbers-of-algorithm2e-package) question, but I think is not, that question is about the position of line numbers within the algorithm box itself, while this question is about the whole content of the algorithm box, with respect to the rest of the text (regular, not part of the algorithm)

Comment: A good, minimal, *complete* document is worth a thousand images. Please add to your question a complete document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: If you feel that this is not a duplicate, please update the question with the relevant information so we can recreate your problem.