# How to put large pseudocode in on slide?

Tags: beamer, pseudocode

I have used the following beamer class for the slides. I have put some algorithms in the slide, **but pseudocode not looking good**

```
    \frame[shrink=25]{\frametitle{Algorithms in Quotient Groups}

      \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \SetAlgoLined
      \textbf{Input} : A group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$\;
      \textbf{Find} : Lists $L_i$'s and the elements $m_i$'s as described 
       above\;
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    Create an array $\it{flag}$ indexed by the elements of $G$ and set $flag[g]  =0, \forall g \in G$\;
      $i \leftarrow 0$\;
    \For{$g   \in G$ }{
    \If{$\it{flag}[g] = 0$ }{

     % Compute $N_1g$\;
     $i \leftarrow i +1$\;
     Prepare a list $L_i$ of size $|G/N|$ with the elements of $Ng$\;
     $m_i \leftarrow \textit { min }L_i$\;  %$\texttt{ linear search on } L_i$\;
     \For{$g_1   \in Ng$ }{
      $\it{flag}[g_1] = 1$\;

    }
    }
}
\caption{Computing lists corresponding to the cosets of $N$ in $G$.}
\label{algo1}
\end{algorithm}



}
```

[image]

**Question :**  Here are few problems, first spacing between the slide title and the algorithm. Second pseudocode left side shifted. Is there any other better way to put psuedocode of the algorithm?

Comment: For the second problem you could take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86580/how-to-adjust-line-numbers-of-algorithm2e-package.